# how to use update statement in android

Tags: java, android, sql-server

i have a script like this

```
UPDATE PS
SET [ShelfNumber] = 'Test'
FROM [file].[ItemPart] PS
JOIN [file].[Item] P ON P.[id] = PS.[id]
WHERE P.[ItemNumber] = 'N84754'
```

and i want to pass it to my statement in my app how do i do that?

i had tryed with this but it doesn't work

```
                String query = "Update PS 
                set ShelfNumber="+edittextshelf+
                "from file.ItemPart PS"+
                "join file.item P on P.id=PS.id"+
                "where P.ItemNumber="+edittextitem;
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strings would appear to be missing separators between the keywords.  Try this:

```
            String query = "Update PS 
            set ShelfNumber = "+edittextshelf+
            " from file.ItemPart PS "+
            " join file.item P on P.id = PS.id "+
            " where P.ItemNumber = '"+edittextitem + "'";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

In addition, you are missing single quotes around `edittextitem`.

In general, you should always use parameters for the query rather than inserting strings directly into the query string.  But that is another issue and unrelated to your original problem.

Comment: thats was it but i running into an exception but not sure if it is the statement or somewhere else in the code